# Swift - Unwrap optional in for in loop with where clause

Tags: swift, option-type, for-in-loop

I have a class with an optional member :

```
class A {
    var i: Int? = nil
}
```

Then I have an array of objects of type `A`. Some objects in the array have a value for `i`, some others don't.

I want to iterate over objects in the array that have a value for `i` while unwrapping the optional at the same time. I didn't find a way to do both at the same time (I don't even know if it's possible), forcing me to write a `if let` construct inside the loop.
For example :

```
// a1, a2 have a value for i
let arr: [A] = [a1, a2, a3]
for obj in arr where obj.i != nil {
    // I want to avoid if let, or force unwrapping here
    if let unwrapped = obj.i {
        print(i)
    }
    // let unwrapped = obj.i! ...
}
```

Is it possible in Swift ?

Comment: Do you need both `obj` and (the unwrapped) `obj.i` in the loop body, or only `obj.i`?

Comment: I need both `obj` and `i` inside the loop indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

Even if you have a **where** clause in your loop the type of **obj** is still of type **A** and as such **i** still remains optional.

To see why this is so think about the fact that you can change the value of **i** on object **obj** inside the loop, so the compiler is not sure that the value of **i** is valid until you unwrapp it.

You can try something like this

```
for obj in arr where obj.i != nil {
  guard let i = obj.i else { continue }

  print( i )
}
```

but if you start using **guard** you also skip the **where** clause

```
for obj in arr {
   guard let i = obj.i else { continue }

   print( i )
}
```

Comment: Alright so my best bet here is force unwrapping it seems. I see the `if let` inside the loop as a repeat for the `where` clause

Comment: there is something you could use, you can use guard, you know the guard condition will never be reached but you don't need to wraps your code in if let

Comment: I just came across this question and found this article, thought I should share it for the future generations :D
https://medium.com/@rizwan95/swift-bit-3-unwrap-optional-values-using-for-in-loop-519e96b6f330

Answer (score 10):

1.Maybe you can use flatMap to get value i, then print it

```
arr.flatMap{ $0.i }.forEach{ print($0) }
```

2.or Trying simple *guard* statement

```
arr.forEach { element in
    guard let i = element.i else { return }
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: flatMap is preferable way to do such things. Check this article about its awesomeness https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-flatmap/

Comment: Your `flatMap(_:)` won't give you both `obj` and `i` inside the loop – only `i`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [case let syntax](https://goshdarnifcaseletsyntax.com), but not without the help of `map`, and the result isn't the most readable:

```
for case let .some(unwrapped) in arr.map(\.i) {
    print(unwrapped)
}
```

It's more useful if you're e.g. casting the outer object, e.g.:

```
for case let object as String in arrayOfAny {
    if object.hasPrefix("tw") {
        print("Starts with 'tw'")
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
for object in arrayOfAny where object is String {
    if object.hasPrefix("tw") { // Error: Value of type 'Any' has no member 'hasPrefix'
        print("Starts with 'tw'")
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer, it can also be written like so:
`for case let unwrapped? = arr { }`